# Beamer \item[Step 1.]

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I want to have something like the following in the beamer

- Step 1. xxxxxx
- Step 2. xxxxxxxxxx

I used

```
\begin{itemize}
\item [Step 1.]{xxxx}
\item [Step 2.]{xxxxx}
\end{itemize}
```

However, in the pdf, the "Step 1" is pushing to the very left of the screen. I've tried to add `\hspace{10mm}` before the `\item [Step 1.]` but it does not work. If I just type `\item Step 1. xxx`, i.e., without the square bracket, everything is find, EXCEPT that when the content after `Step 1.` is too long, then the latex automatically break the line such that in the next newline, it aligned with the `Step 1.` But I want it to aligned with the first letter in the content right behind `Step 1.`

It seems that `\item [Step 1.]{xxxx}` is the only way to do that but it pushes the whole line to the very left of the page. I never encountered this problem with the paper version of latex,  I don't know why beamer has this problem.

Comment: Use `description` instead of `itemize`. BTW, you  can change  `{xxxx}` by `xxx`. There are not mandatory argument in `\item`.

Comment: You might try increasing \leftmargini (default 2.5em or so depending on the document class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `enumerate` environment to automatically get the numbering:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{item projected}{size=\normalsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
text
{
            \setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{
              \usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
              \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
              Step \insertenumlabel.%
            }
            \setlength{\leftmargini}{3.5em}

            \begin{enumerate}
                \item test1
                \item test2
            \end{enumerate}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]